# Relation between the number of children and maternal telomere lengths

Tags: cell-biology, literature, sociobiology

I've read multiple papers with contradictory findings. [Some](https://apha.confex.com/apha/144am/meetingapi.cgi/Paper/360090?filename=144am_Abstract360090.html&template=Word) suggests a strong [negative](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29452389/) effect by birth-giving on telomere lengths. Others [disagree](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0146424). However, none of them establishes causal relations in my humble opinion.

Which study is the most credible?

Comment: I think the first study should rather measure the change in average TL before and after rather than measuring just the after and comparing it to a control because the apparent difference could just be the variability we already normally have. The second study doesn't state how it was carried out. TL increases in dividing cells. For example, cancerous cells have longer telomeres.  It would be a good idea to look at hormones that control cell division and how pregnancy might affect their levels. It can also require multiple births to have a significant effect since pregnancies don't last much.

Comment: @user7777777 Cute analysis! So, none of them are very credible, statistically.